# JS deviceorientation event: how many pixels around the 360 degrees?

Tags: javascript, virtual-reality

When listening to the *deviceorientation* event in the browser, using something similar to

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);
```

we can get the 0-360 degrees from `event.alpha`.

Is there a way to translate the 360 degrees into pixels, so that I can know how many pixels of the window are 'scanned' while turning a full circle?

This can be useful for VR experience of positioning elements at a specific direction.